# How to Pass Smarty variable or array in Chart.js scripts

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I am using chart.js for creating line charts. I am using php and Smarty. I am creating a string and passing it to Smarty .

When I pass that Smarty variable to chart.js it shows syntax error an stops the charts.

So I want to know what is the proper way to use chart.js with php and Smarty.

Any help will be appreciated. That's code I use:

```
var tp = {
    $tot_app
};
var total_app = tp.split(',');
//day applications
var dayp = {
    $dtcnt
};
var day_arr = dayp.split(',');
//dates
var dt_p = {
    $dates
};
var arr_t = dt_p.split(',');
var lineChartData = {
    labels: arr_t,
    datasets: [{
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        data: total_app
    }, {
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        data: day_arr
    }]

}
var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
```

Comment: Welcome. Can you post some code snippets, and the exact error message you are receiving. It will make it easier for people to help.

Comment: ok  i  am putting the code there

Comment: try to add the values like `var tp={/literal}{$tot_app}{literal}`

Comment: Actually I tried this one. It resolved error but does not put the data in proper way. as the code suggests it is a line chart. i have three strings for this. but it not making the chart porperly . i checked it vales are fine. so unable to handle problem.that is why i am looking to pass array of smarty rather than variable.